# Django Rest & React: lookup_field = 'slug' not returning item from db

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I'm trying to return items from my sqlite db such that the url in the browser reflects the slug, rather than the unique post id.

I had this working before by using the primary key, whereby items were returned from the db when clicking a hyperlink for item detail - but swapping everything out for slug is not working.

I have a PostListView in react which lists my items from the db successfully, when I click on one of these the url field in the browser properly shows the slug. However, no data is returned from the db in the underlying detail view.

I am using django 2.2.1, django rest framework and react.

Back end - django and rest framework modules:

**Models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this post')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='')
```

**api/views.py**

```
class PostListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer


class PostDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

**api/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view()),
    path('<slug>', PostDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

**api/serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
''' Serialisers will convert our JSON from web into python model '''
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('post_id', 'slug', 'title', 'content', 'publish_date' )
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Frontend - React:

**PostListView.js**

```
class PostList extends React.Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this function gets called everytime the component is mounted(rendered)
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    posts: res.data
                });
            console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Post data={this.state.posts} />
        )
    }
}
```

**Post.js**

```
const Post = (props) => {
    const { classes, data } = props;
    return (
        <List className={classes.root}>
            {data.map((item, key) =>
              <ListItem alignItems="flex-start" key={item.post_id}>
              <ListItemText
                  primary={<a href={`/${item.slug}`}>{item.title}</a>}
                  secondary={
                  <React.Fragment>
                      <Typography component="span" className={classes.inline} color="textPrimary">
                      {item.content}
                      </Typography>
                  </React.Fragment>
                  }
              />
              </ListItem>
              )}
        </List>
    );
}
```

**PostDetailView.js**

```
class PostDetail extends React.Component {

    state = {
        post: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // this function gets called everytime the component is mounted(rendered)
        const slug = this.props.match.params.slug;
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${slug}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    post: res.data
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card title={this.state.post.title}> 
                <p>{this.state.post.content}</p>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Check "Network" tab in your browser dev tools - does it send request to fetch post details? If yes - does server response look correct?

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov the GET request failed, unsure if it's my lookup code or the lookup itself that's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I needed to change the path handling the routing to PostDetail in my BaseRouter component as follows:

```
const BaseRouter = () => (
<div>
    <Route exact path='/' component={PostList} />
    <Route exact path='/:postID' component={PostDetail} />
</div>

);
```

**To**

```
<Route exact path='/:slug' component={PostDetail} />
```